# how can I query for releases / iterations via rally c# api?

Tags: rally

I am trying to query on both Release and Iteration so I can fill out a drop down list with these various values. I'm not quite sure how to do this, however. What are the members of the object that come back via the query if we are able to do this? (Name, FormattedID, CreationDate, etc). Do we just create a new request of type "Release" and "Iteration" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that queries on releases based on a project reference. If this project is not in a default workspace of the user that runs the code we either need to hardcode the workspace reference or get it from the project.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        RallyRestApi restApi;
        restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "TopSecret1984", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.40");
        var projectRef = "/project/22222222"; //use your project OID
        DynamicJsonObject itemWorkspace = restApi.GetByReference(projectRef, "Workspace");
        var workspaceRef = itemWorkspace["Workspace"]["_ref"];

        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       try
        {

            Request request = new Request("Release");
            request.ProjectScopeDown = false;
            request.ProjectScopeUp = false;
            request.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            request.Fetch = new List<string>()
             {
                 "Name"

             };
          // request.Query = new Query("Project.ObjectID", Query.Operator.Equals, "22222222"); //also works
            request.Query = new Query("Project", Query.Operator.Equals, projectRef);
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
            foreach (var r in queryResult.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + r["Name"]);
            }

       }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("problem!");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the help here. This worked perfectly, and also worked for querying on Iteration